# Symfony Messenger - checking if queue is empty

Tags: symfony, message-queue

We are migrating our architecture to take advantage of the Symfony Messenger component. What I am dealing with at the moment is adjusting the deploy process of our application.

The [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#deploying-to-production) suggests that the workers should be restarted on deploy to pick up the new code. Makes sense. My problem is that this does not address the issue when upgrading the deployed code. Consider hypothetical versions 1 and 2.

Version 1 works with and understands a certain set of messages.

Version 2 adds more message types *and changes the names/structure/whatever* of some  of the message types defined in version 1.

During deploy, in order to be sure that all messages were processed and there are no incompatibilities when the new version, this is the process that makes intuitive sense to me:

- Stop accepting new messages to the queue (put the site to a "maintenance mode")
- Let the workers finish processing pending messages in the queue
- Deploy new code
- Restart workers
- Start accepting new messages

The problem I am facing is that I can't see any way to check whether the queue is empty or not.

Is my deploy scenario correct? How the deploy *usually* done in applications using the Symfony messenger component (or any messaging queue, for that matter)? Is the only way to go ensuring backward compatibility for all the message types?

Comment: Interesting question. Have you ever thought about teqniques like ["green/blue" deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) in order to avoid those kind of scenarios overlapping?
It would be perfect as your strategy is risky when, just for example, the queue is highly congested and it tooks several time to be empty (or similar scenarios)

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about something like that (though I didn't know it has a name). In large-scale deployments where the downtime duration would be a bigger factor, it might be worth the investment. However, for us at this point it would be too much overhead, when we are okay with up to a few hours of downtime when deploying outside of work hours. Our queues will not be _that_ congested at the current deployment scale, so that's not a burning issue either.

Comment: Ok. BTW I've checked and there's stated
"to do this, run messenger:stop-workers on deploy. This will signal to each worker that it should finish the message it's currently handling and shut down gracefully." in the link you've provied, so is trivial for you to reach what you want.

Comment: I've had this question for years (with SimpleBus). It doesn't speak to the problem per se, however I would look at how this is discussed in event-driven systems, e.g., versioning events: https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/07/versioning-event-sourcing/

Comment: Greg Young also has a book: https://leanpub.com/esversioning Personally, feature flags to me seem to make sense in some scenarios for commands. I just don't know I appreciate too much of the techniques for doing so I've seen.

Comment: This is interesting, in this context, since you generally need to consider serializing your messages across boundaries: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#versioning-objects

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting challenge.

**Version 1 (new handlers for the same messages you sent out in the previous release)**

For this you could use Middleware and Stamps to add a version-header to the messages sent over a transport. Then on the consuming side your handler can watch for the version stamp and check if its responsible for this message or not. The upside of this approach is, that you can change the handler logic without changing the message itself just by having the new code add a new version to the same message types you sent out before.

This can easily be introduced to an existing application by having your existing handlers look for the stamp and if it's not there assume they are responsible and otherwise bail out. When a new version wants to introduce a new handler it will only work with whatever version you specify and ignore any messages without this header.

**Version 2 (Modifying data structure)**

One approach to this problem would be to only have backwards compatible changes in your messages and handlers between each release. So for example assume your message looks something like this:

```
{
    "foo": 123
}
```

and you want to change it to something like this:

```
{
   "bar": "123"
}
```

In that case you would first release an intermediate version, containing both the old and new field and after a while you can release the version where you remove the old logic. The intermediate version of the message might look like this:

```
{
  "foo": 123,
  "bar": "123",
}
```

You would then have a Handler that checks for `bar` first and and falls back to using `foo` and the old logic, if `bar` is missing. This way you can make sure that both new and old messages are processed by your new application and by adding logging you can easily see when the old code is no longer called making it safe to remove the old property and logic in an upcoming release.

The main drawback of this approach is, that you will have to catch breaking changes in advance which requires a thorough review and testing process. Luckily failure transports can catch issues when your handler encounters issues, but if the message can not be properly decoded those messages might be thrown out instantly, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks, this is also the approach to use for rolling updates and seamless rollbacks. But as you note, it comes with more work on the database schema change design. Not applicable in my team but still a good solution for some.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Messenger component gives any help with working out the queue length - at least none I found so far.

So the answer depends on what type of transport are you using. For example, with the Doctrine transport you can just count the number of rows in the DB table etc.

The problem with that approach is that you make your code less portable/configurable - if your code expect to count rows in DB table, it won't work with Redis transport, or if the table name changes.

In our project we ended up with a queue counting service that looks into the Messenger configuration and decides how to count the items in the queue.

As for the rest of the question about the deployment, other answers here are good. I'll sum up what we learned when running a clustered Symfony application on AWS ECS with blue/green deployment:

You could treat your message handlers like you would do DB migrations: any two adjacent versions must work with the same schema - so any two message handler versions must be able to work with the same message format.

Turn the handlers off before running a deployment, deploy the new version and turn the handlers on again. If you have multiple versions, you will need to do multiple deployments, one version by one.

You should know before each deployment whether you can just roll out multiple versions at once because there are no breaking changes, or not.

If your environment autoscales, you also need to ensure the handlers are not started on any additional nodes that appear during the deployment and are still serving the older version of the application.

We use a boolean flag in Redis to allow nodes work out whether the handlers should be started or not - that flag is set to "false" just before we halt our current handlers at the beginning of the deployment.

--

If there are any better ways to do this, I'm all ears.

Good luck!